# php: How will I know if the sql query is successfully executed

Tags: php, sql-server

For example:

```
$qrInsert = "INSERT INTO DBASE1.DBO.TABLE1 VALUES ('sampVal','sampVal','sampVal')";
odbc_exec($msCon,$qrInsert);

if( 'the query if successfully executed' ){
//then do this

//if not then
}else{
//then do this

}
```

Is there an easy way to know if it is successfully inserted, or in other cases, updated, and deleted succesfully?

Thanks

Comment: Just simply look at the return value of your call: `odbc_exec`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try like

```
if(odbc_exec($msCon,$qrInsert))
{
    echo 'Executed Successfully';
} else {
    echo 'Error in execution';
}
```

**odbc_exec** only will return true if the query executed successfully,or else return false if it is not

Comment: +1 - PHP manual - `Returns an ODBC result identifier if the SQL command was executed successfully, or FALSE on error`

Comment: is it better if I put it on a variable like the other answers?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (odbc_exec($msCon,$qrInsert)){
// do this
}
else{
// do that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace your code with

```
 $qrInsert = "INSERT INTO DBASE1.DBO.TABLE1 VALUES ('sampVal','sampVal','sampVal')";
  if( odbc_exec($msCon,$qrInsert); )
     {
       //then do this
       //if not then
     }
 else
    {
     //then do this
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It Return 0 or 1 depends on failure or success of your query.You Can store result of "odbc_exec" in a variable & compare it in 'If','Else' condition.Benefit of storing in a variable is ,you can use it where ever you want .

i.e.

$query_result = odbc_exec($msCon,$qrInsert);
if($query_result)
   echo 'Executed Successfully';
else
   echo 'Execuion Error';